# How does BindingResult.rejectValue(...) work with Object[] errorArgs?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

How can I solve this method with the Object[] errorArgs parameter?

Working option Spring Controller:

```
bindingResult.rejectValue("password","error.password", "123");
            bindingResult.rejectValue("password","error.password", "345");
            bindingResult.rejectValue("password","error.password", "678");
            bindingResult.rejectValue("password","error.password", "910");
```

Thymeleaf:

```
 <div class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}">
                        <div th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('password')}">
                            <li class="small" th:text="${err}"></li>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

What would I like:

```
bindingResult.rejectValue("password","error.password", new String[] {"123", "345", "678", "910"}, "");
```

with the same Thymeleaf.

Comment: That is not how it works. You are now passing an array of arguments to a single message. That is not how it works or will work. How should Spring (or rather the resourcebundles) know that you at 1 time have 1 message with multiple placeholders and another 1 message with 1 placeholder and want have multiple messages. What for a combination of these two?

Comment: Hi, I saw an array in the rejectValue parameters and thought that for one error code, you can immediately pass a lot of values in this array so that in Thymeleaf (as indicated in the example) you can output via th:each
 
Collect the 4 lines specified in the Spring BindingResult example in one line and then output them through a loop in Thymeleaf

Comment: Or tell me. I didn't find in the documentation. how to use Object[] from BindingResult in Thymeleaf and Spring

Comment: You don't, thymeleaf integrates with spring and the messages are converted before displaying in thymeleaf.

Comment: Maybe explain why you are asking this question? What do you want to do that you think this would solve?